# Finding a vector that when rotated about the z-axis, spans a line, a plane, or all of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I've been thinking about this problem where I have a transformation matrix $M$ that rotates vectors in space 30 degrees clockwise about the z-axis, i.e.

$M = \begin{pmatrix}
\cos{(-30)} & -\sin{(-30)} & 0 \\
\sin{(-30)} & \cos{(-30)} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

I need to find vectors $\overrightarrow{a}$, $\overrightarrow{b}$, and $\overrightarrow{c}$ such that $\text{span}\{\overrightarrow{a},M\overrightarrow{a},M^2\overrightarrow{a}\}$ is a line, $\text{span}\{\overrightarrow{b},M\overrightarrow{b},M^2\overrightarrow{b}\}$ is a plane, and $\text\{\overrightarrow{c},M\overrightarrow{c},M^2\overrightarrow{c}\}$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

From my understanding of these questions it seems that $\overrightarrow{a}$ could be a vector that remains the same during z-axis rotation such as $\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$, and $\overrightarrow{b}$ could be a vector that satisfies $z=0$ during the rotation such as $\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}$.

However, I can't envision something that would encapsulate all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Something like $\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
1 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$ would make a sort of cone that doesn't end up covering all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, right?

What am I missing to tackle this last question, or am I approaching the question wrong? And also, is my thinking on track for the first two parts of the question?

Comment: Are you sure you understood $\mathrm{span}$? As long as three vectors are mutually not collinear, they span $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @Trebor and all 3 are non coplanar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Span of a set of vectors $\vec v_i$ is the set of all the vectors that can be obtained by all possible linear combinations of $\vec v_i$. If you have three vectors, you can get either a line, a plane, or the whole $\mathbb R^3$.

To obtain a line, all three have to be collinear. You've noticed that if the vector is along $\hat z$, the rotation will not change that vector. So for $\vec a$ you have $\vec a=M\vec a=M^2\vec a$.

You also noticed that if you have a vector $\vec b$ perpendicular to $\hat z$, $M\vec b$ and $M^2\vec b$ are in a plane. To prove that they indeed span a plane, you need to prove that two of them are independent, but the third one can be written as a linear combination of the first two. $\vec b$ and $M \vec b$ are not collinear (the angle between them is $30^circ$). However the third can be written as a linear combination of the first two. You can do this by hand, but to reduce the number of calculations, I will do a trick here. I will use $\vec b$ and $M^2\vec b$ as my independent vectors. They are not collinear, since there is an angle of $60^\circ$ between them. Since they have the same length, the vector sum of them is at $30^\circ$ to each of those, meaning that it's along $M\vec b$. So I can write $M\vec b\propto(\vec b+M^2\vec b)$, so it's a linear combination, and therefore not independent.

Now if you have your vector $\vec c$ along $(1,1,1)^T$ they are indeed on a cone. But now they are independent. To show this, calculate $x,y,z$ such as $x\vec c+yM\vec c+zM^2\vec c=0$. To show that this homogeneous system of equations has only the trivial solution, show that the determinant is not equal to $0$.

Comment: So (1,1,1) and its rotations do in fact span $\mathbb{R}^3$? This is because a "cone" is a 3-dimensional space. I was just simply misinterpreting span.

Comment: Correct. Notice that if you intersect the cone with a plane going through the vertex, you cannot find more than two vectors that belong to both, so the third vector necessarily is not in the plane formed by the other two.